# Make DataTables column variable based on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

**Background:**
I'm busy building a application which (amongst other things) has to be able to show a report. I choose DataTables because it works awesomely and it was easy to implement. I've made an application which is based on one (static) dataset. However, I have gotten the request to alter the application to be able to work with multiple datasets.

**Question:**
Amonst other things, i want to replace the statically defined columns (see code snippet), with a variable. In this case an array with `id, keten, name, x, y`, which will be declared somewhere else dynamically.

How do i change my function to incorporate a variable array instead of hardcoding the columns?

The end result should change from

```
"columns": [
    {"data": "id"},
    {"data": "keten"},
.......
```

to something like

```
"columns": [
    {"data": *variableReportData*}
```

**Code:**

```
function rapport_vullen(){
    $("#rapport").dataTable({
        destroy: true,
      "aaData": geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; }),
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "keten"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "x"},
            {"data": "y"}
        ]
    });
    download_rapport()
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the array of column names into an array of objects by using `.map()` like so:

```
var inputArray = ["a","b","c"]; // for example
inputArray.map(function(d) { return {data:d}; });
```

So the I/O would be:

```
["a","b","c"] --> [{data:"a"},{data:"b"},{data:"c"}]
```

And then create the DataTable using the output.

```
function rapport_vullen(inputArray){
    $("#rapport").dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        aaData: geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; }),
        columns: inputArray.map(function(d) { return {data:d}; })
    });
    download_rapport()
}
```

Comment: I've been tinkering with the code a bit but the results are not 100% correct. Although it returns the correct number of record for my report, all record are [object Object]

Comment: @JordiZ Are you outputting to the console? Try using `JSON.stringify(obj)` when you output.

Comment: When I console.log(inputArray), the console shows an object. When I console.log(JSON.stringify(inputArray), the results are : `[{"data":"id"},{"data":"x"},{"data":"y"},{"data":"keten"},{"data":"name"}]`, which is good I thought. However, when I try to incorporate it in my DataTables, it gives an empty report. Error message: "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e"

Comment: @JordiZ Hmm, that's strange. Can you make a snippet where I can see the code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, while making the snippet I saw I used one function double. Now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript `.map()` function :

it will convert the array elements into the objects as you wanted.

```
var arr = [id, keten, name, x, y];

var objArr = arr.map(function(item) { return {data:item} });
```

console.log(objArr);

```
 [{"data": "id"},
  {"data": "keten"},
  {"data": "name"},
  {"data": "x"},
  {"data": "y"}]
```

Then, you can directly use this in your datatable function. Thanks